# How to read a custom datetimeformat using Pandas in a csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file using Pandas which has timestamps recorded in the following format:

2017-11-24T05:25:00+01:00 where T indicates Time and +01:00 refers to timezone info(CET time).

How should I parse the timestamp?

Thanks,
Debayan

Comment: Have you tried doing `pd.to_datetime(df['your_column'])`? Or on loading do: `df = pd.read_csv('whatever.csv', parse_dates=['your_column'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ItemDate.csv')
print(df.info())
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   Item    5 non-null      object
 1   Date    5 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
```

Then:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert('CET')
df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------  --------------  -----              
 0   Item    5 non-null      object             
 1   Date    5 non-null      datetime64[ns, CET]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, CET](1), object(1)
```